# How to return all elements of a arrary of split function in awk without making a loop to a ksh arrary?

Tags: arrays, function, split, return, ksh

about that i need return all elements from the array split function without loop, but i dont know which it is the sintyaxis, i think that:

```
#!/bin/ksh
set -a MyArray
echo 'hello world' | awk '{
    split($0, arrSplit) 
    print arrSplit[all elements]
}'
```

someone could help me with this?

Comment: please edit your question to show your required output. Did you know about `echo "${myArray[@}}"` If I understand your question, you don't need the `| awk ....` at all. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set an array in ksh, all you need is

```
set -A myArray hello world
echo "${myArray[0]}"    # => hello
```

In awk, the `split` function returns the number of elements produced. To iterate over the array, you need this value

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        n = split("this is a string that I want to split into words", ary)
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            print i, ary[i]
        }
    }
'
```

There are 3 things that are hard about programming: giving things good names, and off-by-one errors.

Comment: thanks, i understand, but i want return the array with all elements without cicle as a parameter to Shell array ksh.

Comment: Then change the `print` line to: `printf "%s ", ary[i]`, and use command substitution to capture the output: `set -A kshArray $(awk ...)`. There's no way to avoid the loop to iterate over the array elements. Why do you think you need awk to do this? ksh is a very capable shell.